# Can you have mesh particles that don’t intersect?

Tags: particles, collision

Hey there I’m just wondering what I should be using if I’m after this result where there’s scattered randomly rotated pills that aren’t intersecting each other like this…

[istock example](https://www.istockphoto.com/au/photo/lots-of-white-pills-gm157683091-14412397)

At the moment mine looks like this where I’ve used a particle system but they’re intersecting.

[image: my example]

or should I be using something else like rigid bodies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should look at the molecular blender addon http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-docs/ it lets you toggle on particle<->particle collisions

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want them to intersect, then yes you should be using rigid bodies.

In the particle system settings, change the start and end frame 1 and adjust the number of particles to fit your scene. That makes all the particles spawn at the same time. Then go into the modifiers tab of the emitter object and click convert. Now each particle should be a separate object.

Then just create a rigid body sim and cache it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that,

in the end I think I’m just going to manually place them as I have more creative control and it was starting to suck up all my memory on my machine.
So end up with something like this rather than the top view I was thinking of.

[image]